# NodeJs - calling one method from another in server controller

Tags: node.js, express

With the following controller, how can I call one method from another in the same controller?

Specifically, calling login() within a successful signup(), while retaining the same functionality for login() when it is used by a form?

The line this.login(newUser) does not work, nor does plain old login(newUser)

In both scenarios, I get the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot call method 'login' of undefined
```

---

```
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');

module.exports = {
login: (function (req, res) {
    req.db.collection('auth').findOne({_id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(req.body.id)},
        function (err, results) {
            // log person in and send results to client
        }
    )
}),

signup: (function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    req.db.collection('auth').insert(user, function (err, newUser) {
            // after adding user, automatically log them in

            // does not work:
            //login(newUser, function (err) {
               // do something
            //})

            // does not work:
            this.login(newUser, function (err) {
               // do something
            })
        }
    )
})
}
```

Comment: I tend to define the function outside of the exports, then it can be referenced both in the exports, and by other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers should be doing as little as possible, and should orchestrate the work required by executing functions stored elsewhere.

View this gist - [click here](https://gist.github.com/reecefenwick/3645c6acfd778fc66660)

What I have done is created "services" that are not tied to the client request, therefore re-usable everywhere.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to Dave Newton**

```
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var myCollection = 'auth';
```

---

**Solution**

```
function localLogin(db, myCollection, user, res){
    db.collection(myCollection).findOne({_id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(user._id)}, 
    function(err, user){
        res.send({ token: createToken(user) });
});
```

---

```
 module.exports = { 
    login: (function (req, res) {
     var user = req.body;
     localLogin(req.db, myCollection, user, res)
   }, 
    signup: (function (req, res) {
       var user = req.body;
         req.db.collection(myCollection).insert(user, function (err, newUser) {
          // after adding user, automatically log them in
          localLogin(req.db, myCollection, newUser, res)
         })
     }
 ) }) }
```